# Terraform how to set "Public network access" Deny service Azure Recovery Service Vault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm, vault

How can I set up "Public network access" Deny Azure Recovery Service Vault service via Terraform?
My provider is version = "2.99.0"
Unexpected attribute: An attribute named "public_network_access_enabled" is not expected here
Thank you

I insert public_network_access_enabled = false into the resources it is not recognized as an attribute.

Comment: Try updating your provider info and try if not please update the code configuration you tried here @Alex